# Handling several thousand redirects with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am working on a site overhaul. As a result I am moving several pages over to a new format. They aren't keeping the same file name as before so the migration is a little tricky.

**Example:**

news.alpinezone.com/93467/ is becoming 
http://alpinezone.com/still-more-skiing-and-riding-at-whiteface/

The news subdomain has accumulated in several years over 3000 articles. Is it OK to put 3000 + 301 redirects into an [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) file?

On a side note, for proper [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization), should I also make sure I use http:// instead of http:// www and also make sure they are fully lower case and also close with a / at the end of the URL. I am redesigning into wordpress and any combination pretty much works but I understand that for Google they can be considered unique but similar URL's so I want to stick with one as much as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache does have some stuff for this, like RewriteMap or RewriteProg. I think htaccess files are read on every request, so I wouldn't want to make the size of it explode with 3000 lines of text - although I gut tells me it would handle it just fine. I think RewriteMap is only loaded once per server start or somethign like that, so thats a benefit.

But personally, I think I would just do an internal rewrite of any request to the news subdomain to a serverside script like php, and then inspect the uri, query the database to get the most current/up to date url slug for the id, and then do an external 301 redirect to the new url.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered mod_authnz_ldap to offload the authentication and authorization lookups to another server? I use this particular module on several enterprise servers with no problems whatsoever. It easily allows you to set up access to pages by group etc.